# How can I step into a function call in the MATLAB debugger?

Tags: debugging, matlab

When I'm debugging MATLAB code, if I call `dbstep` when the next statement is a function call, the debugger skips over the function call to the next line of code in the current m file. How can I step into the function call? I'm looking for a function like `next` in gdb.

**Example**

Source file:

```
=> b = foo(a);
   c = bar(b);
```

I call `dbstep`:

```
   b = foo(a);
=> c = bar(b);
```

What I want:

```
   function out = foo (a)
=>     out = baz(a);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MATLAB alternative to gdb's `next` command is `dbstep in`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option, if you are using the GUI is to learn the keyboard shortcuts, which have been really helpful to me for stepping through code.

Once you are in debug mode, using F10 will step line by line through your current file.  If you want to step in to a function just use F11.  Step out is shift+F11 and F5 will run to the end.